# Changes in Intellij doesnt have any affect on the web program

Tags: java, spring, runtime-error, vaadin, jrebel

Im using Intellij, Vaadin, Spring and JRebel.

I didnt made any changes on my program, but since today my program doesnt work normal anymore. If i try to make any code changes through IntelliJ, normally, JRebel is going to refresh the Website automatically, but since today there is no refresh anymore. If i try to restart the Program, the Website looks just the same like before the code changes, i dont know why, but dont matter what i change, even if i delete all the code and restart the program, its working, but only with the older version and without any changes.
I already tried to delete the "generated" and "node_modules" file, restart the PC, invalidating the caches, restarting the IDE or using the program without JRebel, but no matter what i do, i dont get any changes on the webprogramm, it seems like the file is frozen and Intellij doenst do any code changes to it, if i change the code.
I updated IntelliJ to the newest version, but it still doesnt work and i dont have any idea now.

Some Weird things happened:
If i change the code, so there is an Error in the code and i recompile and restart the program, the terminal doesnt show any error.
If i delete the generated and the node_modules file and restart the program, then oddly, all code changes are applied, but only one time. If i try to make any code changes, there is no change at all, only if i delete the files.
If i make code changes and save them and then restart the pc, there is no change after restart the programm, like the program is locked on a special version and any code change on it, even when saving, doesnt get applied.

Does anybody have the same problem or any idea how i can fix this?
I use git and looked up, if i made any changes, which can impair the program, but i dindt find any.

Comment: Have you tried running in in another IDE like Eclipse? And what happens if you reinstall Intellij?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "web program".  Are you talking about code
that resides usually in the frontend folder (e.g. js/ts/...) or code on
the JVM side (e.g. java/...)? What build tool are you using, how do you
recompile.  Have you tried removing elements of the equation?  What
happens when you compile/run the application from the CLI (outside of
IDEA)?  Does the used build tool allow to ramp up logging (e.g. `gradle
-d` shows excessive debug logging). When you say you _looked_ at the
changes in git, have you actually tried to `git bisect`?

Comment: Im using Vaadin to build web programs without javascript or HTML, moreover only with java. Vaadin automatically compiles the code from java in javascript and HTML, so i only have to code on the JVM side. I use JRebel to build the program, but if i deactivate it, it also doesnt work. I already tried to remove all changes since the last commit, but it still doesnt work.